# Https iframe in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to render an iframe in puppeteer - all well and good so far, it's setup and working. The problem I'm having is that to render an iframe from this url, I need to be on an https url; the error I get is:

> Refused to frame  because an ancestor violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'
> https:".

Is there a way to get this kind of thing working in puppeteer?

Here's the code I have so far:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const embed = `
    <iframe src="<some https url>" style="width: 330px; height: 186px; border: 0px;"></iframe>
`;

const timedPromise = time => new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => { res() }, time);
});

(async function () {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setContent(embed);

    await timedPromise(3000);

    await page.screenshot({ path: `screenshot${Number(Date.now())}.png` });

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: have you tried any launch arguments if they make any difference? (other than the `headless : false`)